# my ajax call wont go into the succes parameter

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax

Why this ajax call will not go into the success parameter what is it that decides if success is true or false. Cause my code works good but success is still false and wont reload my page

```
$(".fa-remove").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");


            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this discount code?")) {
                $.post($(this).data("url"),function(data){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("DeleteUser","Discount")',
                        type: "POST",
                        data: data-URL,
                        success: function () {
                            alert("Deleted");
                            location.reload();
                        }
                    });
                })
                };

        });
    });
```

Comment: your '$.post($(this).data("url"),function(data)' this part is working properly??  try to put error after success and see what you get

Answer (score 0):

Add the "contentType" : "application/json" field in the $.ajax call. And it's a conventional rule to use "type": "DELETE" for delete request.
In the ajax call, if the request type is either "POST" or "PUT", then you have to send the data in the body of the request. For that the data should be stringify first. And in java script a data variable cannot be declared as "data-URL". Please remove "-" in between data and URL.
In below I give an ajax call for POST request.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:8000/add",
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: JSON.stringify(dataURL) || {},
  success: function(data){
    console.log("successfully added", data);
  },
  error: function(error){
    console.log("error", error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Reasons**

- url: '@Url.Action("DeleteUser","Discount")',
- data: JSON.stringify(dataURL) || {},